# How to filter list from another list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
names = ['aet2000','ppt2000', 'xxx2001', 'ppt2001']
wanted_list = ['aet','xxx']
```

What I want to do is to get list in `names` that contain string in `wanted_list`.

I can use this, which I manually put `aet` and `xxx` in the filter function.

```
In [17]: filter(lambda x:'aet' in x or 'xxx' in x, names)
Out[17]: ['aet2000', 'xxx2001']
```

But it doesn't use the list `wanted_list`. How can I do it?

Comment: `'aet' or 'xxx'  in x` is wrong, anyway, because it means `('aet' or 'xxx')  in x`, and the latter is simply `'aet' in x`. What you need is `'aet' in x or 'xxx'  in x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a list comprehension:

```
>>> [name for name in names if any(substring in name for substring in wanted_list)]
['aet2000', 'xxx2001']
```

Answer (score 2):

As DYZ said,`aet` or `xxx` in x is wrong,it will return all elements in `names`,I suppose this is you want:

```
names =['aet2000','ppt2000', 'xxx2001', 'ppt2001']
wanted_list = ['aet','xxx']

print filter(lambda x:'aet' in x or 'xxx'  in x, names)
```

Or you can try this:

```
print [j for i in wanted_list for j in names if i in j]
```

By the way,maybe `startswith` also can do this:

```
print [j for i in wanted_list for j in names if j.startswith(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to pull out the part of the string you want to match and check if that is in the list.

```
>>> import re
>>> names = ['aet2000','ppt2000', 'xxx2001', 'ppt2001']
>>> wanted_list = ['aet','xxx']
>>> [name for name in names if re.match(r'[^\d]+|^', name).group(0) in wanted_list]
['aet2000', 'xxx2001']
```